# How to control amount of fluid in Mantaflow?

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

i want to start my simulation with a low amount of water and it should increase after some hundred frames more and more.
Unfortunately animating the velocity variables is not working that well and scaling the emitter is not working because it´s made of single faces in one object. And i can´t scale the emitting faces with "individual origins" as keyframes.
Any workarounds?

Comment: can u provide blend file? "normally" velocity would be the right thing to use...what do you mean with "not that well"?

Comment: thank you, what velocity option is the best to animate?

Comment: I would try normal…then you can rotate the emitter if you want and it still works while animating

Comment: the emitting object is not moving or rotating... it´s just emitting like a faucet.  but i will try it with normal velocity, thank you!

Comment: i set the normal velocity to -2 for the start, after 100 frames it goes to 0. and it´s still a huge amount of fluid in the beginning..

Comment: Every other value than 0 will emit fluid. The higher the absolute value is, the more fluid will come. Positive or negative values are just different for the direction of the fluid. So just lower the values - to e.g. 0.3

Comment: not working.. from 0.0 to 0.3 keyframed for example produces still a huge amount of fluid in the beginning.. should i scale my emitting faces much more down?

Comment: So please provide blend file…so I can check it out

Comment: another fileupload:  https://filehorst.de/d/eIFnfmiq

Comment: Hello? Did you check it out?

Comment: i cannot download your file....i have no idea why. Could you please use a more common cloud service like dropbox, onedrive...or google?

Comment: what version of blender is your file?  I was able to download it, but I opened a 25Mb file with no objects in 2.93.5

Comment: it´s Blender 3.1

Comment: One thing you can try is to animate the surface emission, however that would mean that the water would start to appear from more than the object's face.  Ah but you want to start with a lower amount than your object gives when surface is 0.0 I bet...

Comment: In your file, you don't need both a Fluid collision effector (keep) and a Physics Collision modifier (remove) on your Toke.003 unless it is involved in other types of Physics (collide with cloth, for example).  Not needed for the other Toke objects either I would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to animate the surface emission, however that would mean that the water would start to appear from more than the object's face.  Instead you could have a hidden dup of your emission object that is the actual emission object, scaled down to your minimum flow.

[image][image]  And here is your [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p96ied94nl1czet/TempleAnim2MantaflowProblem_2a.blend?dl=0) with similar.

I'm still downloading 3.0, but probably similar in 2.93.5...

You could try a trick where you have a hidden (non-renderable) collision object that is the same shape as your emitter object, and you could vary its scale to have it interfere more or less.

[image][image]

Another idea is to animate the particle radius:

[image]
[image]

I finally got blender 3.0 installed.   The blender uploader doesn't seem to recognice 3.x file yet, so here is a [Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x89iznixlfma3jh/TempleAnim2MantaflowProblem_2.blend?dl=0).

Comment: thx.. i will try that!

Comment: Decreasing particle radius leads to the opposite.. the fluid is getting clumsy and blown up. think i should adjust the mesh particle radius as well...

Comment: @flonkplonk -- Yes I can imagine some side effects on all of these suggestions, also depending on your mesh-flow object.

Comment: @flonkplonk You want to INCREASE particle size to slow down the flow. I left a link to your file that I edited with the example of my third suggested technique.

Comment: @flonkplonk I also added a Dropbox link to your file edited with my first example of animating Surface Emission instead of Particle Radius.  Just an example as you'd probably want the initial flow to be smallers (by scaling the Toke_Wateremitter object).

Comment: thanks James! will look into it!

Comment: Great! Thanks, James! the animated particle size example is great, the one with animated emission has still very very thick fluid in the beginning... i even tried something and scaled my emitter faces extremely down and there was absolutely no thinning of the initial water emission..

Comment: @flonkplonk -- these indirect methods in these arcane applications can be hair pulling exercises!  Hopefully you still have some left ;-)

Comment: James, it´s only try and error... animating particle size (like in your example) now leads to the flow playing reverse! :D  so the fluid goes back to the emitter for a short time which looks really strange... i think i will buy another fluid addon, MantaFlow is completely strange and irrational..

Comment: and "arcane" is a great term :D or "quantum mechanic effects"...